# $\ell_\infty^*$ has Dunford--Pettis property

Tags: banach-spaces

hi, I'm trying to prove that $\ell_\infty^*$ has the Dunford–Pettis property. It's enough to show that $\ell_\infty$ does not contain a copy of $\ell_1$ … but I'm having some trouble doing that. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Homework? Maybe you should take this question over to [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead. It is more likely to be positively received there. Also, when you do ask, say a bit about what approaches you have tried.

Comment: Here is an addition to your homework assignment: Prove that $\ell_\infty$ has a subspace isometrically isomorphic to `$\ell_1(2^{\aleph_0})$`.

Comment: right. Here's my  approach. I found this result that says that $X^*$ has DPP iff $X$ has $DPP$ and doesn't contais a copy of $\ell_1$. So I'm trying to show that $\ell_\infty$ does not contain a copy of $\ell_1$ . I found a result that says that if $T\colon X \to \ell_1$ is bounded linear and onto then $X$ contains a complemented copy of $\ell_1$. It looked like I could use this to prove the result by contradiction, showing that $\ell_\infty$ has a complemented copy of $\ell_1$, which is absurd, since $\ell_\infty$ is prime. 

But I got stuck, I'm afraid I got the wrong road.

Comment: Suppose $T\colon \ell_\infty \to \ell_1$ is an isomorphism onto it's image. Then $T^{-1}\colon \mathrm{Im} \; T \to \ell_1$ is onto, bounded and linear. Therefore $\mathrm{Im} \; T$ contains a complemented copy of $\ell_1$. So I can see that $\ell_1$ is a complemented subspace of a (not complemented) **subspace** of $\ell_\infty$. I can't seem to close the gap. Is this the right approach ?


Comment: The question was posted at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/219454/8297

Comment: Yes, I'm following Harald's advice and trying both foruns.